# Object-oriented jump table defined over multiple classes

Tags: c++, 6502

I am in the midst of refactoring a NMOS6502 emulator into multiple classes. I was wondering if there is an "object-oriented" way to define a function jump table. Basically, I have defined separate instruction classes to classify groups of related cpu operations- like "CStackInstHandler" or "CArithmeticInstHandler" which will have a reference to a cpu object. Each instruction class is derived from an abstract instruction class. Each derived instruction class has a set of functions which will use the cpu object's public interface to change the cpu state e.g:

```
uint8_t opcode = _memory->readMem(_cpu->getProgramCounter());
AInstructionHandler* _handler = _cpu->getInstHandler(opcode);
_handler->setCpu(&cpu);
_handler->setMemory(&memory);
_handler->execute(opcode);
```

The problem is that at runtime an instruction handler as well as the appropriate member function defined for that handler needs to be determined using an opcode.

So we have - opcode is read from memory, a table is used by the cpu to map opcode to instruction handler type, and then the same opcode is used by the instruction handler to select the correct function. Each instruction overrides an "execute" function e.g:

```
void CBranchInstHandler::execute() {
    switch(_opcode) {
        case 0x90:
            this->BCC();
            break;
        case 0xb0:
            this->BCS();
            break;
        case 0xf0:
            this->BEQ();
            break;
        case 0x30:
            this->BMI();
            break;
        case 0xd0:
            this->BNE();
            break;
        case 0x10:
            this->BPL();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

}

```
void CBranchInstHandler::BCC() {
    uint16_t address = this->getAddress();
    if(!_cpu->isCarry()) {
        uint16_t pc = _cpu->getPC();
        pc += address;
        _cpu->setPC(pc);
    }
}

/*more instruction specific functions...*/
```

I end up with two look-ups, one of which is redundant. One to select the handler, and another to select the handler function. I feel like this is the wrong way to accomplish this task, but I am not sure of an alternative that doesn't just devolve into groups of non-member functions.

I am wondering if anyone has insight into this problem. It basically boils down to wanting to refactor a class into smaller bites (cpu class with instruction member functions refactored to cpu class and instruction classes), but the all of the components are so interrelated that I end up having to repeat myself. Redundancy is introduced.

A non-object oriented solution would be to just have these instructions be non-member functions that accept a cpu reference. Then, a function jump table would be defined, instructions would be looked up and indexed by opcode and executed.

This doesn't really seem practical with objects. I could make all the instructions static or something but this seems to miss the point.

Any insight or information about even tangentially related problems would be super helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Does getAddress affect isCarry?

Comment: It does not. getAddress just returns the current program counter and isCarry just checks whether or not the carry bit is set at this point in time.

Comment: So why put it outside the if?

Comment: I see where you are coming from. You are right, it should be within the if statement. Also, getAddress() returns the effective address, not the pc.

Comment: There is probably a nice object oriented solution involving functors/lambdas, but let me add this early: Don't be afraid to use a code generator or judicious use of the preprocessor. Instruction sets tend to be pretty dense, so you wouldn't be wasting your time with a fixed array to make those lookups super cheap, but maintaining such things is a pain.

Comment: If you want to stick to this categorization of instructions, why not let the handlers register themselves with the CPU object (which would boil down into something like a lookup table in the CPU object being filled with the addresses of all opcode-handlign methods)? Then to execute an opcode you would do `_cpu->execute(opcode)`.

Comment: Dumb question, perhaps: if it's just a design question, why not just call every `execute`? Classes that don't handle a given opcode know they don't handle it and will just do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to promote my comment to an answer: the object-oriented solution is, as you say, to give the child classes full responsibility for deciding which opcodes they respond to.

I'd suggest that the easiest way of doing that isn't to try to build a two-stage `switch` but simply to route every opcode to every child and let the child either contribute or not. That's the minimum viable solution.

If you need an optimisation then the easiest thing would be to reformulate:

```
void CBranchInstHandler::execute() {
    switch(_opcode) {
        case 0x90:
            this->BCC();
            break;
            ... etc ...
    }
}
```

To:

```
FuncPtr CBranchInstHandler::execute() {
    switch(_opcode) {
        case 0x90:
            return BCC;
            ... etc ...
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

So each `execute` returns whether it in fact handled that opcode.

Within the parent class you could then simply keep a table from opcode to function pointer. An array will do. The table will initially contain `NULL`s throughout.

When performing an opcode, look up the handler in the table. If the handler is there, call it and move on. If not then call `execute` on every child in turn until someone that returns a handler, then put them into the table and then call it. So you'll build it just-in-time, at runtime. The first run of each opcode will take slightly longer but you'll subsequently have what amounts to a jump table.

The advantage of that is that it allows the information about what a child handles to be tied closely to the actual handling of it syntactically, reducing code overhead and the probability of error.

Comment: This is great. Just one question - how do I store a function pointer to a member of class? Or would the methods being handled by the instruction handlers need to be non-members/ or would the managing class need to be a friend of the instruction handlers?

Comment: I'm a bit out of the loop on the latest C++ advances but certainly the classic approach would be that BCC, etc, are static class methods that take `_cpu` (or, I guess, just `cpu`) as an argument. I've assumed your child classes have no storage because it seems likely in 6502 emulation context.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pointer to class member function/method:

```
void (CBranchHandlerBase::*)();
```

Using for store the pointers to the methods which should be invoked for given `_opcode`.

```
map<uint8_t, void (CBranchHandlerBase::*)()> handlers;
handlers[0x90] = &BCC;
handlers[0xb0] = &BCS;
...
```

The code above should be provided in the initialize section/method inside your base class for the handlers. Of course BCC, BCS and so on must be declared as pure virtual methods to make the approach work.

Then instead of your switch:

```
void CBranchHandlerBase::execute() {
    (this->*handlers[_opcode])();
}
```

Note that execute is defined in the base class (and it does not have to be virtual! as each Handler will have the same functionality of execute method).

**Edit:** The map actually can be replaced by the vector or array of size: `2^(8*sizeof(uint8_t))` for efficiency reasons

Comment: Why a `map`? It doesn't have constant time lookup, does it?

Comment: `std::array` would probably be better in this scenario.

Comment: But I think the problem is that you're specifying "CBranchInstHandler" whereas he seems to have different instruction types each having different handlers - so he'd need to use the CBranchHandlerBase, which breaks the model...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, what you are doing is creating a class for each type of instruction (Branch, Arithmetic, Load, Store, etc) and then within those you are writing member functions for the individual instructions -- c.f. you have a "CBranchInstrHandler" which handles "branch on carry", "branch on zero" etc?

The fully Object Oriented approach is to extend your subclassing down to individual instructions.

```
class CBranchInstrHandler { virtual void execute() = 0; };
class CBranchOnCarryClear : public CBranchInstrHandler {
    void execute() override {
        ...;
    }
};
class CBranchOnCarrySet : public CBranchInstrHandler {
    void execute() override {
        ...;
    }
};
```

Now you can look your instructions up in one shot, but you'll need a one-to-one mapping of all of these.

```
switch (opCode) {
    case 0x90: return .. CBranchOnCarryClear .. ;
    case 0xB0: return .. CBranchOnCarrySet .. ;
}
```

The elipsis are there because I'm not sure how you are getting a pointer to your CBranchInstrHandler; I'm guessing that they are static and that you aren't `new`ing them every instruction.

If they are dataless, you can return them as function objects by value:

```
struct Base { virtual void execute() { /* noop */ } };
struct Derived { void execute(override) { ... } };

Base getHandler(opcode_t opcode) {
    if (opcode == 1) { return Derived(); }
}
```

but I suspect you probably want to take parameters and store state, in which case return by value here could result in slicing.

Of course, if you are using C++11 you could use lambdas:

```
switch (opCode) {
    case 0x90: return [this] () {
        ... implement BCC execute here ...
    };
    case 0xB0: return [this] () {
        ... implement BCS execute here ...
    }
}
```